# How to set values from an excel sheet to Pojo object using apache-poi?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, collections, apache-poi

I am trying to get values from an excel sheet using apache-poi and than to enter those values into a mysql database.Using apache-poi I am able to get values by using XSSFSheet.rowIterator() xssfrow.cellIterator();This excel sheet provides me 10000 rows and 180 columns.

Now I want to to enter those excelsheet provided values to a table using hibernate framework  .so I have created a pojo in my java application which have 180 attributes in it ,So have 180  getters and 180 setters.

Only way I can think setting these values to pojo attributes  is to iterate column iterator and then call setter method of pojo. I  am curious to know that can there be any smarter or more efficient way for doing it?

Note : I  have tried to normalize table but as there is no  repetition of data so I don't think that table can be normalized

Comment: How do you know which setter to call for the `next` value in the iterator? This seems a very odd design. I could understand if you 180 values were in a `Map` where the key was the field name or name of the setter.

Comment: How do you know which value matches which setter? Can you give us some example of data you iterate through.

Comment: Actually I am trying to fetch values from an excel sheet and then store those values to a database.I am using apache POI api.By which I get values using iterators.

Comment: So you have a table with 180 columns as well?

Comment: Did i read it right 180 getters and setters? You really need to delegate your code.

Comment: @sp00m: yes.. I tried to normalize the table but can't as all 180 columns are difference and I can't find any duplicacy or reduncdency.

Comment: @M.Sharma : I don't have any other option.

Comment: @JohnB: I have edited question, which now provides complete information of scenario :)

Comment: I'm not sure it will be good for your case or not but just retieve the full row of the excel and store it in a multimap. You can serialize the Map into a binary object and store that in the database as a BLOB

Comment: @M.Sharma: I need to do many searches on the basis of those column values.Thats why I am trying to map those values of excel to Database.Saving a complete row as Blob will not allow me to do searches on basis of column as now I have complete row saved as a Blob data type.Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as I see it you have two options: use an Enum or Refection. Either way you will need to produce a Map where the key is the field specifier and the value is the value to store in that field.

I suggest you read the first row to get the column names and map them to field name. Then as you read each data row produce a `Map<FieldSpecifier, value>`.

If you are using reflection the field specifier would be the field name. Use the field name to determine which setter to call.

If you are using the Enum, you would have an Enum of 180 values. There would be an abstract method (setValue) that is implemented in each Enum instance to call the appropriate setter. Then the field specifier in the map is the appropriate Enum instance. Then just iterate the Map Entries calling the key.set method passing the DTO instance and entry value.

Answer (score 2):

Could possible do something like this. Would only work for non-primitives atm. Could check if value extends number and do primitive check aswell.

```
public class ValueInserter<T> {

    public T objectCreationImplementation(Map<String, Object> methodValueMap, Class<T> clazz) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, InvocationTargetException {
        T o = (T) clazz.newInstance();
        for (String parameter: methodValueMap.keySet()) {
            Method method = clazz.getMethod(getSetterName(parameter), methodValueMap.get(parameter).getClass());
            method.invoke(o, methodValueMap.get(parameter));
        }
        return o;
    }
    private String getSetterName(String parameter) {
        return "set" + parameter.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + parameter.substring(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, you should use entrySet instead of keySet since you need both the key and value. No point in doing the map lookup (map.get) when iterating. Especially since you called get twice.